# Flutter change splash screen background color

Tags: android, flutter

I have this default code in my `launch_background.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Modify this file to customize your launch splash screen -->
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/white" />

    <!-- You can insert your own image assets here -->
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

I would just like to know, how do I change this `<item android:drawable="@android:color/white" />` to a custom colour, something like `<item android:drawable="@android:color/#FFF8DC" />`

Comment: Is there a reason why you're wanting to do it on the android side while using Flutter? You can just have your entry point into your app be a SplashWidget, which handles all your auth/loading logic, and then take advantage of FLutter's easy to use Theming scheme

Comment: @android:color/white is just a reference. Did you try to replace the whole string with e.g. #000000?

Comment: @AlanNegrete When a Flutter app is launched the background specified in `launch_background.xml` is rendered on the screen for an indeterminate amount of time while the Flutter framework initializes. Changing this let's you better apply your app's brand to the launch experience on Android.

Comment: @ChanceSnow Gotcha! I guess it has always loaded so fast for me that I haven't even noticed it tbh!

Answer (score 52):

Create a file `android/app/src/main/res/values/colors.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <color name="red">#FF0000</color>
</resources>
```

Edit `android/app/src/main/res/drawable/launch_background.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Modify this file to customize your launch splash screen -->
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/red" />

    <!-- You can insert your own image assets here -->
    <!-- <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@mipmap/launch_image" />
    </item> -->
</layer-list>
```

Comment: How does it know?

There is no importing there. Please do enlighten me

Comment: Because convention.

Comment: Ahaa got you boss

Comment: thanks. It works greatly. I faced one problem as used android:drawable="@ **android:** color/white" instead of  android:drawable="@color/red". May be useful to someone.

Comment: Please keep in mind you also need to change the drawable-v21. <item android:drawable="@color/red" /> instead of <item android:drawable="@android:color/white" />

Comment: And for ios ? what i should do for ios ?

Answer (score 9):

Create `colors.xml` file in your `app/src/main/res/values` folder and in that file write

```
<color name="yourColor">#FFF8DC </color>
```

Then in your `launch_background.xml` file use it with,

```
<item android:drawable="@color/yourColor" />
```

Comment: This is not working. I am getting this error `android\app\src\main\res\values\colors.xml:1:50: Error: Premature end of file.`. I had to delete the `colors.xml` file for it to go away (uncommenting everything in the file didn't help)

Comment: Can you share the screenshot? I am not sure how you did it

Comment: The reason you are getting the error is that is not the complete code for colors. It needs to be formatted as  xml . Use the previous code snippet

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="yourColor">#C2002F</color>
</resources>

Answer (score 2):

For reference, I also needed to update the `launch_background.xml` of the `drawable-v21` folder in the same manner. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71390884/13738523