# How to change background color(own color) of launch screen?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to add my own background color to launch screen i tried [Flutter change splash screen background color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56583735/flutter-change-splash-screen-background-color) but it didn't work i got error . Any other way to change it ?

Comment: Can you share error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use plugin for splash screen then use below plugin. it's easy to use [flutter_native_splash 0.1.9](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_splash)

Comment: Do i need to call flutter pub pub run flutter_native_splash:create .Everytime if i want to change color again ?

Comment: Yes, It's will regenerate file in Android and iOS for a splash screen with an update data