# Splash Screen Color not Changing in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, splash-screen, flutter-android

I am new to Flutter and still practicing

I am creating a splash screen but the color of splash screen is not changing

My Code:

-launch_background.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <!-- Modify this file to customize your launch splash screen -->
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:drawable="@android:color/black" />
    
        <!-- You can insert your own image assets here -->
        <!-- <item>
            <bitmap
                android:gravity="center"
                android:src="@mipmap/launch_image" />
        </item> -->
    </layer-list>
```

-main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:id_locker/Screens/HomeScreen.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: HomeScreen(),
    );
  }
}
```

-HomeScreen.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:hexcolor/hexcolor.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(color: HexColor("#2301FA")),
    );
  }
}
```

It should ho black screen but it still white screen
SS:
[image]

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56583735/flutter-change-splash-screen-background-color

Comment: I have already seen that , but it is not working neither yt tutorial , I don't know , What's the Problems

Answer (score 6):

You also need to change in `launch_background.xml` file of the `drawable-v21` folder the same as of the `drawable` folder.

Change

```
<item android:drawable="?android:colorBackground" />
```

to the tweaks you made `@android:color/black` (or `@color/backgroudColor` for the custom-defined `colors.xml` file);

```
<item android:drawable="@color/backgroudColor" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you edit the `launch_background.xml` in the `drawable` folder?  You may need to edit the `launch_background.xml` in the `drawable-v21` folder instead.  Or, just use the [flutter_native_splash](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_splash) package that I maintain.

Answer (score 1):

You can set & change it for booth themes light & dark simply using [flutter_native_splash](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_splash).

First of all, you need to add the following line to **pubspec.yaml** file under `dependencies:`

```
flutter_native_splash: ^1.3.1
```

Then add `flutter_native_splash:` as new section to **pubspec.yaml**.
Now you can set the splash background color for light and dark themes by adding the following lines under `flutter_native_splash:`

```
color: "#ff8a84"
color_dark: "#ad5f5c"
android: true
ios: true
```

android & ios added to supply booth OS's

In the end, the **pubspec.yaml** file will look like this:

[image]

Now to generate the splash screen:

- open the terminal in your fluter project
- run this command: `flutter clean && flutter pub get && flutter pub run flutter_native_splash:create`
- start your application :D

If the background color does not change, uninstall the application from the phone/simulator and then start your application again.

For more details enjoy [Johannes Milke's tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ME8Czqc-Oc).

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <!-- Modify this file to customize your launch splash screen -->
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:drawable="@color/bg" />
    
        <!-- You can insert your own image assets here -->
        <!-- <item>
            <bitmap
                android:gravity="center"
                android:src="@mipmap/launch_image" />
        </item> -->
    </layer-list>
```

create colors.xml in res->values and paste code:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>
        <color name="bg">#f00000</color>
    </resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you've updated your `colors.xml` (*android/app/src/main/res/values/*) and both `launch_background.xml` (*android/app/src/main/res/drawable* & */drawable-v21*) files and it's still not working, make sure your `styles.xml` (*android/app/src/main/res/values/*) file points to the color you want like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="LaunchTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/launch_background</item>
        <item name="android:windowSplashScreenBackground">@color/yourColor</item>
    </style>
    <style name="NormalTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/yourColor</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```